# Ajax loading content from specific URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that loads content via ajax only when a users clicks a specific link on that. But now I want to be able to load that specific content if the user is brought to that page from a external link with that specific argument in the url.

Here is the jquery that loads the conent on the current page. This page is at mysite.com/portfolio. A portfolio item only shows up when a users clicks a link on that page.

```
 $('.portfolio-load').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: this.href, 
              success: updatePortslide, 
              dataType: 'json', 
              data: 'js=2' 
            });

            return false;

    });
```

How would I modify this to work if a users comes to this page from an external link like mysite.com/portfolio/name-of-content-to-load

Answer (score 0):

on document ready use regex and extract the name-of-content-to-load from the url and call the $.ajax it should work. but u may have to change the this.href to the appropriate url.

Answer (score 0):

what about checking the referral ? are you using php ?, if yes the you can try using refferal instead, like

```
if($_SERVER[’HTTP_REFERER’]!=''){
    echo "<script>
        $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.href, 
            success: updatePortslide, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: 'js=2' 
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>";
}
```